# Fastest way to get difference between List<object>

Tags: c#, list, tree, duplicates, set-difference

I'm developing a program which is able to find the difference in files between to folders for instance. I've made a method which traverses the folder structure of a given folder, and builds a tree for each subfolder. Each node contains a list of files, which is the files in that folder. Each node has an amount of children, which corresponds to folders in that folder.

Now the problem is to find the files present in one tree, but not in the other. I have a method: "private List Diff(Node index1, Node index2)", which should do this. But the problem is the way that I'm comparing the trees. To compare two trees takes a huge amount of times - when each of the input nodes contains about 70,000 files, the Diff method takes about 3-5 minutes to complete.

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
private List<MyFile> Diff(Node index1, Node index2)
    {
        List<MyFile> DifferentFiles = new List<MyFile>();

        List<MyFile> Index1Files = FindFiles(index1);
        List<MyFile> Index2Files = FindFiles(index2);

        List<MyFile> JoinedList = new List<MyFile>();
        JoinedList.AddRange(Index1Files);
        JoinedList.AddRange(Index2Files);
        List<MyFile> JoinedListCopy = new List<MyFile>();
        JoinedListCopy.AddRange(JoinedList);
        List<string> ChecksumList = new List<string>();

        foreach (MyFile m in JoinedList)
        {

            if (ChecksumList.Contains(m.Checksum))
            {
                JoinedListCopy.RemoveAll(x => x.Checksum == m.Checksum);
            }
            else
            {
                ChecksumList.Add(m.Checksum);
            }
        }

        return JoinedListCopy;
    }
```

And the Node class looks like this:

```
class Node
{
    private string _Dir;
    private Node _Parent;
    private List<Node> _Children;
    private List<MyFile> _Files;
}
```

Comment: Can you (or have you) sort the entries prior to comparing them? IIRC, sorted collections generally offer better performance in terms of searching.

Comment: @KennethK. And hash based structures offer faster searching than sorted collections.

Comment: @Servy Agreed. But a `List` is being used. There is no hashing going on with a list so far as I know. In order to hash, wouldn't a new data structure need to be used (e.g. `Dictionary` or `HashTable`)? *edit I suppose you could write a hashing function for the existing list, since a `List` is indexable.

Comment: @KennethK. Yes.  You will actually save a *lot* of time creating a new hash-based structure based on what's in the list then searching the list N times.

Comment: How would your code handle a single Folder containing multiple copies of a file.  I have to admit that I dont know everything there is to know about Checksum, but would the file a.txt, and Copy Of a.txt, have the same Checksum since they are identical in every way other than name and physical disk location?

Comment: @Nevyn There's also the issue of checksum collisions, although I don't think any of our solutions handle that case properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than doing lots of searching through `List` structures (which is quite slow) you can put the all of the checksums into a `HashSet` which can be *much* more efficiently searched.

```
private List<MyFile> Diff(Node index1, Node index2)
{
    var Index1Files = FindFiles(index1);
    var Index2Files = FindFiles(index2);

    //this is all of the files in both
    var intersection = new HashSet<string>(Index1Files.Select(file => file.Checksum)
         .Intersect(Index2Files.Select(file => file.Checksum)));

    return Index1Files.Concat(Index2Files)
        .Where(file => !intersection.Contains(file.Checksum))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: WOW! This perferms so well compared to what I was doing ealier. It takes about 5-8 seconds to compare the two 10mb of index files generated, which each contains 70,000+ files. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    public static IEnumerable<MyFile> FindUniqueFiles(IEnumerable<MyFile> index1, IEnumerable<MyFile> index2)
    {
        HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var file in index1.Concat(index2))
        {
            if (!hash.Add(file.Checksum))
            {
                hash.Remove(file.Checksum);
            }
        }

        return index1.Concat(index2).Where(file => hash.Contains(file.Checksum));
    }
```

This will work on the assumption that one tree will not contain a duplicate.  Servy's answer will work in all instances.

Comment: I seriously question that this would be the "fastest" approach.

Comment: @Oliver Your code right now is just performing a `Distinct`.  That's not what he wants.  He wants just those values not in another set.  If a value is in both sets it shouldn't be returned at all, but your code yields it once.

Comment: Oh, and FYI there's no need for an iterator block for your whole `foreach` loop, you can just use `Where`.  `return index1.Concat(index2).Where(file => hash.Add(file.Checksum));`

Comment: Based on your new edit it won't properly handle the case where a given element is in the sequence more than once.  If it's in both sets but in one set twice (so a total of three times) your code will yield it, even though it's in the other set.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that would situation would occur in this case?

Comment: @Oliver It's hard to say if it's possible or not in this particular case without knowing more about the system.  It does prevent the algorithm you've shown from working in the general case though, which is, at a minimum, something future readers should be aware of.  It's easily solved too; just see my answer, which even reads pretty much like the requirements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26192/discussion-between-oliver-and-servy)

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping the entire FileSystemObject for every element in the tree?  If so I would think your memory overhead would be gigantic.  Why not just use the filename or checksum and put that into a list, then do comparisons on that?

Comment: I would assume because he needs the rest of that data somewhere else.  He could always re-fetch it if he stored path information alongside filename, or AS filename...but we dont know what the rest of his code looks like

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this is more than just a "distinct" function, what you are really looking for is all instances that only exist once in the JoinedListCopy collection, not simply a list of all distinct instances in the JoinedListCopy collection.

Servy has a very good answer, I would suggest a different approach, which utilizes some of linq's more interesting features, or at least I find them interesting.

```
var diff_Files = (from a in Index1Files
                 join b in Index2Files
                 on a.CheckSum equals b.CheckSum
                 where !(Index2Files.Contains(a) || Index1Files.Contains(b))).ToList()
```

another way to structure that "where", which might work better, the file instances might not actually be identical, as far as code equality is concerned...

```
where !(Index2Files.Any(c=>c.Checksum == a.Checksum) || Index1Files.Any(c=>c.Checksum == b.Checksum))
```

look at the individual checksums, rather than the entire file object instance.

the basic strategy is essentially exactly what you are already doing, just a bit more efficient: join the collections and filter them against each other to make sure that you only get entries that are unique.

Another way to do this is to use the counting function in linq

```
var diff_Files = JoinedListCopy.Where(a=> JoinedListCopy.Count(b=>b.CheckSum == a.CheckSum) == 1).ToList();
```

nested linq isn't always the most efficient thing in the world, but that should work fairly well, get all instances that only occur once.  I like the approach the best actually, least chance of messing something up, but the join I used first might be more efficient.

Comment: Your first option wont' work.  When you do the join you get the intersection of the sets, so you've already excluded all of the values that you need.  You actually need the exact *opposite* of what the Join returns.  By the time that you get to the `where` you've already "lost", so to speak.

Comment: For the other two, they're both doing linear searches on the lists for each item in the other sequence.  Very inefficient.  They're shorter than the OP's code, but of similar runtime complexity.

Comment: not really, notice that the where clause is working against the original two sets...you are exluding things from a and b then joining the result...I have to say you are correct about the other two options though, less efficient, but much prettier :-)

Comment: The `Where`, in the first case, is applied to the results of the Join.  When the join finishes what the sequence is, fundimentally, is pairs of objects, one from each set, that match.  That's *exactly* what needs to be excluded, and contains none of the values that should be returned.  Further filtering isn't even worth looking into, all of the values you need to return have already been filtered out.

Comment: so you are saying that while the join would work, the actual answer would be to take the joined result, without the where, the apply it to his `JoinedListCopy` and remove each value contained in my `diff_Files` variable?

Comment: An inner join is, fundamentally, an `Intersect` that uses some other key to compare against, rather than the object itself, and also that applies a projection to the results rather than returning the object from the set.  If you look at my code I find the intersection, then return all items from either set that aren't in that intersection.  Your `Join` finds that intersection.  You could then return all items not found in the result of that Join, and it would work.  With `Intersect` being a special case of `Join` that happens to apply here, I used it instead as it results in shorter code.